# Does my desire for extra information on Deuteronomy 22:1-3 warrant a separate question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently asked the following question:

[Does Deuteronomy 22:1-3 apply to stray pets (e.g., dogs)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128736/does-deuteronomy-221-3-apply-to-stray-pets-e-g-dogs)

It seems the answer is "Yes." However, I'm not sure whether it applies if I live with my parents, and they tell me to avoid stray dogs since such animals may be dangerous. I wonder if I would be exempt in such a scenario due to 1) the fact that I should obey my parents and/or 2) the fact that, per the scenario, I don't have a house to keep the dog (but rather, my parents). A third consideration, that dogs *can* be dangerous (as opposed to Deut. 22:1-3's harmless examples of an ox, sheep, donkey, or garment), may be relevant as well.

Asking about such considerations is similar to my question linked to above, but it's also different. Would it justify a separate question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would justify a separate question in my opinion, but the specific separate question you wish to ask is [not a good fit for this site](/q/3760) and should instead [be asked of your rabbi](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

Comment: Ah, I see. If I reworded the question to instead be about already-existing sources, would the question be broadened sufficiently? For example, "Are there _sources_ addressing what to do if 1) a lost animal is potentially dangerous or 2) one lacks a place to put a lost animal?"

Comment: Actually, I think https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760 is very relevant here. I should've said so from the start. I'll edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: Looking at your link, I find that even my modified idea doesn't survive the three arguments for closure you offered. Instead, maybe I could ask if any sources address whether Deuteronomy 22:1-3 applies to dangerous animals. That would avoid the scenario of combining multiple aspects into one. It would 1) seem have general interest (at least in the sense of being useful for many people), 2) be broader than a personal situation, and 3) invite answers. What do you think?

Comment: That sounds great.